# Encountering issue when trying to get changes to an item in OneDrive via api

Tags: onedrive

We are using the OneDrive python sdk, and when trying to get changes for an item we are seeing

```
{"error":{"code":"invalidRequest, "message":"You cannot get the content of the current version"}}
```

This worked yesterday, and we haven't changed anything. Any ideas?